# problem with tcp server and client

Tags: java, networking

Hii all, I have already created some programs related to client and server. Today it was my sessional[practical exam] of Client-server technology.

Problem was: i was to add two no's at server sent from client and result back to client.

I tried this solution but some strange solution was there:
Server.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(7896);
        Socket cs = s.accept();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cs.getOutputStream()));
        bw.write(br.read() + br.read());
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 7896);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
    bw.write(3);
    bw.write(4);
    System.out.println("Output is: " + br.read());
}
}
```

when i ran it on dos prompt i got two blank screens; one at client site and one at server site(which was a bit surprising). then i closed server then suddenly i got error msg at client something like connection closed.

Then i ran same program on my ubuntu linux with same jdk 1.6 as it was in windows, and here also blank screens but when i closed server i got:

```
Output is: -1
```

Although in exam i done this using DataOutputStream and DataInputStream.

But why the above code is not working.

Can Anyone explain what is happening in the code there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments which might help you reach the correct answer:

- The server code as it is can accept
  only a *single* client request since
  the `accept()` call isn't present in
  an infinite loop.
- When using buffered
  streams, make sure you *always* flush
  the `OuputStream/Writer` to ensure
  that the data is *actually* written
  to the client instead of just lying
  around in the buffer.
- DataInput/OutputStream is absolutely required (or any other approach which logically reads the "number" string and converts it to an appropriate representation which can be added) since just *reading* from the `BufferedReader` doesn't fetch you the "numbers".

But the question is, why flushing is required? To answer this question, one has to understand why "buffering" is used in the first place. Why bother wrapping your streams in another stream when you can directly write to your stream? The reason is that I/O operations are *really* expensive (at least when compared to accessing your RAM or CPU cache/registers). Frequent writes/reads accessing/writing small chunks of data to the HDD can choke up your HDD and bring down the overall performance of your application.

So what's the solution? Write data to the HDD less frequently. Two ways this can be achieved:

1. Manually allocate a large byte array
   and fill up the entire array in a
   single read. This is way better than
   single byte reads. The byte array
   size does require tuning as per your
   application needs but for general
   purposes 8K should be good to go.
2. Use a buffered stream. This has the advantage of not exposing the clients to the low level details. Your application can use the "stream" as it sees fit (continuously writing single bytes to it) and the stream would assume the complete responsibility of *flushing* the *buffered* data when it sees fit (this depends on the buffer size which you set when creating a buffered stream).

Though the explanation was HDD specific, the same applies to other types of stream like in your case socket.

TL;DR: Buffering improves IO throughput/performance. :)

Comment: Hey sanjay after flushing this worked fine. but can you tell me why flushing is necessary?

Comment: @codeomntrix, because the writer is buffered, and buffering means you control when the data is sent.

Comment: @peter then does it means it would not be received until buffer is full. but what if i close the program in middle then what happens to messages available in buffers? and one more thing would the same will happen if i close the streams?

Comment: @codeomnitrix: Hi, I've updated my original answer with the response.

Comment: hey thanks sanjay. i will take care of this in future. and thanks for clearing my doubt

Comment: If you fill the buffer, flush() or close() the writer, the data will be sent. If the program dies any unsent data will be lost.

Comment: @Peter: Good point; I had always assumed this was an obvious thing given the way buffering works but it is better to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

[`write()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) will buffer input so it does not need to do lots of small writes. Since you are not writing much to the buffer, it is probably still there and not written out yet. Calling [`flush()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush%28%29) will force it to write out the buffer.

Comment: Hey unholysampler thanks for response ya this works. but can you tell me what actually happen if i don't flush the buffer and the input just be there in buffer. and since tcp is reliable option and it ensures delivery then why this is necessary

Comment: TCP ensures delivery once data is passed down to the transport layer. Your `BufferedWriter` is at the application layer. It is buffering your input __before__ passing it to TCP.

Comment: then what if i close the stream would it be delivered or not. and what actually happens to message remain there in buffer. and one more would this work if i will have small buffer size of say 4 bytes

Comment: The documentation for `Writer` says `close()` calls `flush()`, but `BUfferWriter` only says `close()` closes the stream. Based on that it seems like you need a manual `flush()`, which makes sense anyways for when the program gets more complicated and requires a back and forth between the client and server.